# dynamic query google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I was experimenting with Queries in Google App Engine using Python. Can't I do something like this?

```
region = '"Malaysia"'
result = Post.query(Post.page_market.IN([region])).order(Post.created_time)
```

But if I do this,

```
result = Post.query(Post.page_market.IN(["Malaysia"])).order(Post.created_time)
```

the query is working.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I got the answer and you can write it like this:

`markets = 'Malaysia, North America'.split(',')
result = Post.query(Post.page_market.IN(markets)).order(Post.created_time)`
I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you don't want the quotes around the region name itself:

```
region = 'Malaysia'
```

Comment: I removed the quotes around the value of the region but it still the same. I would like to have this code accept more than one value dynamically but it seems like it's not supported.